Custom Theme – conflict with new plugin search
I’ve got a custom theme. Everything use to work perfectly fine (February of this year). Now I cannot search for new plugins within Wordpress. It just displays the spinning circle. When I activate a default wordpress theme, the plugin page works fine. Any ideas? Anything new that must be in themes over the past couple of months?
The theme is a Block Theme.
Does any wordpress updates come to mind that may cause this to conflict?
Any thoughts you have would be great. Semi New to developing with wordpress. Trying to get my head wrapped around it. The theme was working perfectly but just noticed this issue.  Haven't tried to add any plugins in a while.

Are you able to post any error message seen in the browser console when the issue occurs? Otherwise its a very open-ended question given its a custom theme..
